# How to Group the form_type and the latest date in Relation with Larevel ORM

Tags: laravel

```
Table LALG
  A_UUID

Table Certification
  A_UUID
  B_UUID
  FORM_TYPE
  FORM_DATE
```

I got the data:

```
Table A
  A0001
Table B
  A0001, B0001, Form 3, 2022-03-25
  A0001, B0002, Form 3, 2022-05-25 
  A0001, B0003, Form 5, 2022-07-25
  A0001, B0004, Form 5, 2021-02-25
```

My ORM

```
$summary = Lalg::with(['certificate'])
            ->get();
```

My Relation In LALG MODEL

```
public function certificate()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Certification', 'lalg_uuid', 'lalg_uuid')->orderBy('certification_date', 'desc')->groupBy('form_type', 'lalg_type');
    }
```

How can I get the Max:date with a different Form Type and Group the Form Type?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this way hope it can be useful

```
public function certificatewithMaxDate()
{
    $query = $this->hasMany('App\Http\Models\ Certification','lalg_uuid', 'lalg_uuid')
        ->addSelect('A_UUID', 'B_UUID','FORM_TYPE','FORM_DATE', \DB::raw("MAX(certification.FORM_DATE) AS max_date"), \DB::raw("MIN(certification.FORM_DATE) AS min_date"));
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ketan Vekariya , i have been tried your code. But it does not work. Thanks